# Processing not rendering video in embedded enviroment

Tags: video, processing, embedded-linux, odroid

I am using Processing, trying to playback a video, on a odroid board. I also use the video library.

I run the sketch on my desktop which works fine. When I try to run the same sketch in the odroid, although everything seems correct. I get nothing where the video was supposed to be, neither an exception, nor any terminal output.

I am sure the native libraries are installed correctly (gstreamer etc), and that the file is correctly located by the sketch.

The code I try is the example here:
https://www.processing.org/reference/libraries/video/Movie.html

Any clue of how to debug this?